# Difference in meaning between people and persons?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, grammatical-number

I've seen there are already multiple questions on the difference between persons and people as plural for person. The answers usually seem to suggest that there's a difference in usage (legal/formal vs everyday/informal contexts) but I wonder if there can be also a difference in meaning.

For instance, let's compare these two sentences:

> Only 5 people are allowed to be in the chamber

> Only 5 persons are allowed to be in the chamber

If I heard the first sentence, I would not be sure if this means that only 5 random people are allowed to enter the chamber at a time or that only 5 specific people have the right to do so.

If I heard the second sentence, I would be much more inclined to believe that it is referring to a limit of people allowed to be inside the chamber at any given time rather than to specific people.

Is my understanding correct? Can there be a difference in meaning between these two words?

Comment: Notices in lifts (elevators) say that they are designed to carry up to X number of persons, clearly meaning bodies as freight rather than individuals.

Comment: [Perhaps this can provide some guidance to some degree.](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00048.htm#:~:text=The%20noun%20people%20has%20both,ending%3B%20it%20is%20already%20plural.)

Comment: When I hear *people*, I think of a mass group without distinction. When I hear *persons*, I think of a group of individuals. Which actually contradicts the previous comment by @KateBunting. Mass freight (in elevators), to me, would be better served by *people*, whereas the use of *persons* emphasizes individuality. I think it's because *persons* uses the normal technique of adding an *s* to the noun, whereas *people* doesn't.

Comment: 'Persons' is more formal than 'people' ; even discounting this, FF has pointed out elsewhere that they're not fully interchangeable ('they had tasers about their persons'), and the 'person' ... 'personal' notional link _does_ mean that 'persons' connotes more familiarity, more of the individuals concerned. 'People' is more impersonal.

Comment: Please don't write answers in comments; they are harmful to our site. Doing
so bypasses our community-moderated quality measures by not permitting
community editing or paired up- and down-voting available on comments, as
well as having [other problems detailed on
meta](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1644/3171). Comments 
are for clarifying and improving the question; please don't use them for
other purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think this shows an underlying difference in meaning. The fact that “persons” sounds like legalese is enough to explain what you describe.

It would be very strange for a law (or other formal rule) to state “There are five people/persons are allowed to be in the chamber” (but we won’t tell you who they are).

So in a sentence that uses phrasing reminiscent of a law or formal rule, the natural interpretation of “five persons” is as a quantity giving a limit, rather than a set of five specific but unnamed persons.

“Only 5 people are allowed to be in the chamber“ would tend to take the same interpretation if understood as a law/rule. But because it uses more conversational wording, in a different context, it could function as a statement rather than a rule.

“Persons” can refer to a specific set of people: e.g.:

> (b) The initial Board of Directors of the Tahoe Resource Conservation District shall be composed of **the following five persons** who shall each be an owner of land within the area described in Section 9951 :
>
> (1) One person appointed by the California Tahoe Regional Planning Agency [...]

(https://codes.findlaw.com/ca/public-resources-code/prc-sect-9952.html)